# Definition of not divisible by

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, definition

I am trying to prove where a bogus proof has gone wrong. I think it is in its definition of not divisible by c but I am unsure what the actual definition is. Maybe I am reading it wrong but shouldn't the definition be n=ck+d where k⋹Z, d⋹Z such that d is not a multiple of c? Thanks!
[beginning of the proof I need help with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk2Er.png)

Comment: The statement in the image is specifying the remainder when you divide by $c$ and asserting that it's not $0$. Your statement is logically equivalent but less restrictive so less useful.

Comment: Please include all relevant details in the post itself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by definition:
if $n$ is an integer and we divide by $k$ then euclid's algorithm states:

$n=qk+r$

$r$ is the remainder, by definition
$0\leq r< k$.

now, if $k$ divides $n^2$ and $gcd(k,n)=1$
then $k|n$.

proof:

$kx+ny=1$
multiply both sides by $n$:

$knx+n^2y=n$

then $k|knx \land k|n^2\implies k|n$.